# Selecting a row from a MySQL table which matches a touple specified in Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am actually a student trying to build a login/registration functionality within my project. I'm receiving errors in fetching an entire row from mysql which matches the tuple of input-based variables specified in Python and am unsure how to proceed.

In detail: so my intent is to take input from the user in the form of a username and a password and then match it to preexisting rows in a table in MySQL. but my code does not seem to work.

Here is the code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username, password LIKE '%s','%s'"%(username,password))
ecreds = cursor.fetchall()
if len(ecreds) == 1:
print("Login successful. Welcome, ")
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=`?

Comment: Are you developing this app using a framework (like Flask or Django)? User authentication is a common task and one that has a best-practice solution already implemented in pretty much every web app framework. Unless this is purely an academic exercise and not something that you intend to put into production, trying to roll your own is not advised.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you compare two columns. Compare each of them and combine with `AND`.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = %s AND password = %s", (username,password))
```

Also, use a prepared statement rather than string formatting to substitute variables in SQL. See  [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)